# Backup software that backs up on file modification

Tags: windows, backup

I'm looking for (ideally free) software that can perform the same functions as Google's previous Backup & Sync software (now called [Google Drive for desktop](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124)), except that instead of backing up to Google Drive, it backs up to an external physical drive.

Specifically, the functionality I am looking for is software that allows me to:

- Choose which specific folders I want to backup.
- Constantly monitor and automatically backup any changes made within those folders on my local disk (file additions, deletions, modifications, etc.)

Does anyone know of any software out there that performs these tasks when the modifications happen, rather than at a set "backup time" on a schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the type of software I was looking for is "file synchronization software" rather than "backup software".

Once I figured that out (after posting this question) I was eventually able to find **[FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/)** which seems to have all of the features I am looking for!

**UPDATE:** After using FreeFileSync for a bit now, it does exactly what I was looking for and can back up all changes to my watched files straight to Google Drive whenever the changes happen!